# does Sequelize can trace query info or has setGlobalTraceFunction just like mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i want to trace all queries information (include spent time) by Sequelize, but i don't want to add log to every query statement.is there any functions or events can make this happen? just like mongoose setGlobalTraceFunction.

mongoose.Mongoose.prototype.mquery.setGlobalTraceFunction(traceQuery);
traceQuery is a function that can log query information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `logging` option in the `options` argument to the [constructor](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/sequelize/):

```
var db = new Sequelize(database, {
  logging : function(query) {
    console.log(query);
  }
});
```

However, I don't think it's possible to log the time it took for the query to run.